# Loop code is displaying pages but not actual posts

Tags: loop

This code only returns the name of a custom page I built -home. Why is it returning the page title? I want to display posts.

```
 <?php
     if ( have_posts() ) {
     while ( have_posts() ) {

    the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation in the comments:

```
<?php
/* This is your original loop (`have_posts`). Even on a custom template, the first loop references
the PAGE to which your template is-- this being your homepage. In order to display posts,
you must use a new query, as in the next chunk of code. */

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Here is how to get posts:

```
/* You can replace your original loop with the code below. This will query 10 posts
and return their titles.
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for customizing it. */

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```